# Facebook Connect w/ Mobile Web App - How to get most fluid flow?

Tags: html, facebook, mobile-website

I'm developing a mobile wep app, and would like to allow my users to login using Facebook connect.

I initially implemented the standard Oauth2 authentication, but I found a couple issues:

- When I install the app as a [home screen shortcut](http://knol.google.com/k/joe/iphone-apps/zvf22hhi9x92/2#Homescreen_Shortcuts) and the user needs to authenticate the user is redirected to facebook's site for authentication in normal safari. When the user is redirected back, the user is still in safari (with the top and bottom nav bars). This is obviously sub-optimal as I'd like to have the full-screen appearance
- I can't get logout to work properly, there appears to be a `m_user` cookie left on facebook.com that is the username of the user that was previously logged in.

I thought, perhaps, that I could switch to the javascript SDK for facebook connect and render a pop-over instead of the redirect dance, but it looks like this is a pop-up only experience. When I try it on the simulator it appears the home screen shortcut is broken out of to safari, and then after login the user isn't even logged in (and the screen remains blank).

Any ideas on the smoothest way of using Facebook connect on a mobile web (HTML5) app, especially if the homescreen shortcut is to be retained?

thanks!

-simon

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest Javascript SDK to accomplish this?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/